# Download PDF in background without opening a browser in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application through which users can download specific document.

I have used List view to display the list of items and each list item has been linked with a specific URL address such that on clicking on the item , users can download the particular file.

On implementing  that I notice, on tapping the list item a browser opens and downloads the PDF .
I want that to happen in  background without opening the browser and notify once the download is complete .

Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: Use `HttpURLConnection`. Or, use OkHttp3. Or, use Volley. Or, use any number of other HTTP client APIs for Android.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) solution